# Bash Script SFTP return code comparison

Tags: bash

I have 1 question regarding sftp, if i successfully connect to the server, and uploaded the file, it will RETURN 0, if server is not connected it will RETURN 255.

The $? variable return 0 if success, return 255 if failed, but somehow in the if-else statement, the result will always be success even $? returns 255, any idea? i not sure if the way of comparing is correct or not, i tried both compare with string and int

```
sftp $ftpuser@$ftpaddr <<_FTP>>$ftplogs
cd /$DEST_DIR
mput $FILE_NAME*
quit

pwd >> $ftplogs
_FTP


echo $?;

if [ $? -eq 0 ];  
then 
    mv $FILE_NAME* $ARCHIVE_DIR
    echo "Success"  
elif [ $? -eq 255 ]
then
    echo "Failed"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Unknown error"
    exit 1
fi
```

RESULT:

Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

255

Success

Comment: i tried remove echo $?;
and
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; 
then
...

but this time it will go to "Unknow error"

Comment: ah, nvm, i found it...my error..lol...thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `$?` is reset on each new function called, so you must capture it once and inspect that variable instead:

```
rc=$?
if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then
# ...
```